# Animation effect for the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way possible to apply animation effect to images in my about section,here is the code:

```
<div id="about" class="row section bgimg3">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h2 style="color:black;">Want to Know More About me?</h2>

        <h3>BIOGRAPHY</h3>

        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Born:1961,dharmavaram</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>spouse:swarna latha</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>parents:Nagi reddy(father),sarada(mother)</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>education:B.A,L.L.B,P.H.D</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>children:Divya,Tejasvi,Saisree</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Achievements:Great father,Public Prosecutor</h4>

        <h3>Hobbies</h3>

        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Partying with friends</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Playing Cricket</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Reading Books</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Travelling</h4>

        <h3>Goals yet to achieve</h3>

        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>World tour with family</h4>
        <h4 style="color:ash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Buy an AUDI</h4>                   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
            <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>
            <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>
            <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>
    </div>
</div>

<hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
```

Here is my link to code pen: https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/WjVjMW

What i want to do is there are three images in my about section,i don't want to display all the three images at a time,i want to appear one by one when i click on about section in header!I want to use animation for this!

Comment: since you are using jquery, did you check lightbox plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library https://github.com/michalsnik/aos . Is very simple the implementation and you can get delay for any class.

Example: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to implement it, since you are using jQuery, you can try fade in effects, like the example https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/bRbpwM

adding this event to your about tab, and hiding the circled images

```
$(".img-circle").hide();
var iteration=1;
$(".1").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top},
                         'slow');

  $(".img-circle").hide();
  $('#'+iteration+'-img-circle').fadeIn(2000);
  if(iteration==3) iteration=1;
  else iteration++;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jQuery:

```
$(".1").click(function() {
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(1)").hide();
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(2)").hide();
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(3)").hide();
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(1)").fadeIn(2000);
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(2)").fadeIn(4000);
  $(".col-sm-4.pull-right img:nth-child(3)").fadeIn(6000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code.

```
$('.img-circle').mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).animate({
    'border-radius': '40%'},
                 'slow',
                 function(){
    $(this).animate({
    'border-radius': '50%'},
                 'fast');
 });
})
```

This working code will help you.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function () {
   $(".0").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
    },
            'slow');
   });

   $(".1").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    },
            'slow');
   });

   $('.img-circle').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
     'border-radius': '40%'
    },
        'slow',
        function () {
         $(this).animate({
          'border-radius': '50%'
         },
             'fast');
        });
   })


   $(".2").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#family").offset().top
    },
            'slow');

   });
   $(".3").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#blog").offset().top
    },
            'slow');

   });
   $(".4").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#testimonial").offset().top
    },
            'slow');

   });
   $(".5").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#spec").offset().top
    },
            'slow');

   });




   $(".6").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
    },
            'slow');
   });
   $(".overlay + img").each(function () {
    var w = $(this).css("width");
    $(this).prev(".overlay").css("width", w);
   });
  });
 </script>

 <style>
  #blog a {
   color: Bisque;
   text-decoration: underline;
  }

  .bgimg {
   background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
  }

  #over img {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
  }

  .jumbotron {
   background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRygQnWzs3GfysYKie99aTXhbYvGrS7gxQzTAFFu9DN4azC_nwz");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
  }

  h3 {
   text-color: black;
  }

  #family h2 {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
  }


  #Nav h3 {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .text {
   white-space: nowrap;
   color: black;
   font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .overlay {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
   /*   background-color: white; */
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 0;
   transition: .5s ease;
  }

  .ovparent:hover .overlay {
   height: 100%;
  }

  .ovparent {
   position: relative;
  }

  #over {
   text-align: center;
  }

  .bgimg1 {
   background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJRGtOjps8wjohBoCFu3oDrwu4O6RakP9KgUbbBHPdoFb_MuUs");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
  }

  .bgimg2 {
   background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
  }

  .well.first {
   background-color: Bisque;
  }

  .well.second {
   background-color: LightGoldenRodYellow;
  }

  .well.third {
   background-color: Thistle;
  }

  .well.fourth {
   background-color: Pink;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="Nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://codepen.io/saisree/full/WjVjMW/">Anand Reddy</a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ">
   <li class="active"><a class="0" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="1" href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a  class="2" href="#family" >Meet the family</a></li>
   <li><a href="#blog" class="3 ">Blog</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#testimonial" class="4">Testimonials</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#spec" class="5">Specialization</a></li>
   <li ><a class="6" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="jumbotron myjumbotron ">
   <section class="bgimg" id="home">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <h1 style="color:white;" class="text-center">ANAND REDDY</h1>
   <h3 style="color:white;" class="text-center">A WONDERFUL SERENITY HAS TAKEN POSSESSION OF MY ENTIRE SOUL, LIKE THESE
      SWEET MORNINGS OF SPRING WHICH I ENJOY WITH MY WHOLE HEART
   </h3>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </section>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <div id="about" class="row section">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2 style="color:black;">Want to Know More About me?</h2>
      <h3>BIOGRAPHY</h3>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Born:1961,dharmavaram</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>spouse:swarna latha</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>parents:Nagi reddy(father),sarada(mother)</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>education:B.A,L.L.B,P.H.D</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>children:Divya,Tejasvi,Saisree</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Achievements:Great father,Public Prosecutor</h4>
      <h3>Hobbies</h3>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Partying with friends</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Playing Cricket</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Reading Books</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Travelling</h4>
      <h3>Goals yet to achieve</h3>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>World tour with family</h4>
      <h4 style="color:ash">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>Buy an AUDI</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
      <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>  
      <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>
      <img style="height:500%;"class="img-circle" src=" https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFp8CA_CfnnMbFZ2UW1cDm_zfDcQtuPitWa0x8LNRKFV3kH4A "/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <div id="family" class="gray-bg">
   <section class="container section team-3col ">
      <div class="row">
      <header class="text-center sec-heading">
      <h2>Meet the Family</h2>
      <span class="subheading">We are the ones!</span>
      </header>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      <div class="a col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      <div class="a col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      <div class="a col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      <div class="a col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-sm-50 ovparent">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <img style="height:100%;width:100%; " class="img-responsive " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsl7JTXK1z2ZomjuzpU49t7TlSMdYcioHrQLvHjmuM_3r5oc36 " />
      </div>
      </div>
   </section>
   </div>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <div id="blog" class="section bgimg1">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <h1 style="color:Bisque;" class="text-center">Welcome to my Blog</h1>
   <h2  style="color:Bisque;" class="text-center">"Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest"</br>
      Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up
   </h2>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5  col-md-offset-1">
      <h2 >
      <a href="#about">Know about my backgound</a>
      <h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">                                      <h2>  <a href="#spec">Know about my specialization</a></h2></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"><h2>  <a href="#contact">Contact My Firm</a></h2></div>
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
   <h2 class="text-center">     <a href="https://codepen.io/saisree/full/WjVjMW/">Visit my portfolio</a></h2></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <div id="testimonial" class="section">
   <div class="section-header">
   <h2 style="color:white"; class="text-center">Testimonials</h2>
   <h4 style="color:white"; class="text-center">
   We have worked with hundreds of clients. Check what our awesome happy clients saying about us. 
   </h4>
   </div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <div class="row"> 
   <div class="well first col-md-3 ">Amazing experience one can ever have!He walked us through the process and made it easy. he answered our questions, no matter how trivial (even on the weekend!), and took time out of her day to come to our home, rather than making us come to him!~<span><a href="#">@abcdefg</a></span>
   </div>
   <div  class="well second col-md-3">Amazing experience one can ever have!He walked us through the process and made it easy. he answered our questions, no matter how trivial (even on the weekend!), and took time out of her day to come to our home, rather than making us come to him!~<span><a href="#">@abcdefg</a></span></div>
   <div class="well third col-md-3">Amazing experience one can ever have!He walked us through the process and made it easy. he answered our questions, no matter how trivial (even on the weekend!), and took time out of her day to come to our home, rather than making us come to him!~<span><a href="#">@abcdefg</a></span></div>
   <div class="well fourth col-md-3">Amazing experience one can ever have!He walked us through the process and made it easy. he answered our questions, no matter how trivial (even on the weekend!), and took time out of her day to come to our home, rather than making us come to him!~<span><a href="#">@abcdefg</a></span></div>          
   </div>                                          </div>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <div id="spec" class="section bgimg2">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>  
   <h2 style="color:black" class="text-center">So, what will I actually be doing?</h2>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey" class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>Attending court hearings (and doing the preparation beforehand)</h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>                                            Drawing up contracts and other legal documents </h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>                                           Negotiating (not all cases will end up in court)</h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Explaining the law and giving general legal advice </h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>                                             Settling disputes and supervising any agreements </h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>Researching and gathering evidence</h3>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>Analysing legal documents</h2>
   <h3 style="color:SlateGrey"class="text-center">                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>Supervising legal assistants.</h3>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </div>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black" />
   <section id="contact">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
      <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
      <hr class="primary">
      <h3 style="color:black">Ready to discuss your next case with me? That's great! Give me a call or send an email and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
      <h3><a href="anandreddyv.25@gmail.com "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">986-60-32199</a></span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
      <h3><a href="anandreddyv.25@gmail.com "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">anandreddyv.25@gmail.com</a></span></h3>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </section>
   <hr  style="border: 1px solid black " />
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
 <footer class="text-center ">
    <p>Copyrights &copy; <span class="text-primary"><a href="# ">anand reddy vennapusa.</a></span> All Right Reserved.</p>
    <p>Developed By : <a href="https://codepen.io/saisree/full/VbEdqW/ " title=" ">saisree vennapusa</a></p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```